# How to search-replace content within files in Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: file, ubuntu, replace

My platform:  Ubuntu linux workstation

In a directory, I havea series of files, with file name xxx_1.in to xxx_50.in

For each file, I want to replace abc to def.  If I do it individually, I should type :g/abc/s//def/g

How to write a script to process all of the files at once?

Comment: I cleaned up some of the grammar and clarified the title.

Comment: Are you replacing `abc` with `def` in the file's contents, or in the name? I'll do both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/abc/def/g' xxx_*.in
```

should be enough

Answer (score 0):

I like Python, even for shell scripting. I can't really figure out how to use `sed`, so I stick to Python's search and replace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, glob

for filename in glob('xxx_*.in'):
  os.rename(filename , filename .replace('abc', 'def'))
```

So as an inline script which runs when you copy/paste it into Terminal (I don't have Python on my current machine, so no guarantees),

```
python -c "import os, glob; eval('for f in glob(\'xxx_*.in\'):\n  os.rename(filename , filename .replace(\'abc\', \'def\'))'"
```

---

It seems like you meant the file's *contents*. *That*, I can do without Python (hopefully this works):

```
for f in xxx_*.in; do sed s/abc/def/g "$f"; done
```

Comment: Be sure to quote the file name variable, as in `"$f"`.